# The time dilation in an oscillating elevator

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

Suppose you are in an elevator which oscillates vertically with a frequency $\nu$. 
How will we find the time dilation in this oscillating reference frame ? 
If the lift is accelerating upward or downward with a constant acceleration, time inside the elevator is given by $t'=t_{0}\,(1+gh/c^2)$. 
I want to know, How to generalize this equation for a non constant acceleration (i.e an oscillating frame of reference)?

Comment: You have two effects. Firstly there's the effect of changing you height, i.e. gravitational potential, but also there is timer dilation due to their velocity you're moving at. You might want to consider a simpler experiment that separates these effects.

Comment: What do you know about the 4-vector traced out by observers?  Can you describe the motion of your observer through space?  Putting these two together will almost instantly give you an answer.